# What is the purpose of BoolQuery's "filter" in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I read the documentation of [BoolQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and according to it, this the purpose,

> **filter**
>
> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike
>   must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are
>   executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and
>   clauses are considered for caching.

Also from BoolQueryBuilder class:

```
   /**
     * Adds a query that <b>must</b> appear in the matching documents but will
     * not contribute to scoring. No {@code null} value allowed.
     */
    public BoolQueryBuilder filter(QueryBuilder queryBuilder) {
        if (queryBuilder == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("inner bool query clause cannot be null");
        }
        filterClauses.add(queryBuilder);
        return this;
    }
```

but I can't get my head around, this. When should I use filter vs (should or must)

Here is the example I am working on :

> I want to filter out some records based on the following assumptions :
>
> Fetch All
>
> 1) Records where `deleted=0` and `isPrivate=true`
>
> **AND**
>
> 2) Records where `(isPrivate=false or [isPrivate=true and
>   createdBy=loggedInUser])`

Here are the 2 queries which give the same result, I want to know what `filter` query signifies

**Result without Filter using just must and should clause.**

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "deleted": {
              "value": "0",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "isPrivate": {
              "query": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "isPrivate": {
                    "value": "false",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "createdBy": {
                          "value": "1742991596",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "isPrivate": {
                          "value": "true",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

**Query with using filter**

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1,
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "deleted": {
                    "value": "0",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "isPrivate": {
                    "query": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "isPrivate": {
                    "value": "false",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "createdBy": {
                          "value": "1742991596",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "isPrivate": {
                          "value": "true",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should definitely use `bool/filter` since you don't have any constraint that contributes to scoring, all constraints are yes/no matches, and by using `filter` you can benefit from filter caches (which you don't when using must)

So definitely go with the filter option, but with a slight modification (you don't really need must at all and your boolean logic is not properly translated to bool queries):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "deleted": {
              "value": "0",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "isPrivate": {
                    "value": "false",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "createdBy": {
                          "value": "1742991596",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "isPrivate": {
                          "value": "true",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So to sum up:

- `should` = OR condition
- `must` = AND condition (when scoring is desired)
- `filter` = AND condition (when scoring is not desired and/or when you want to benefit from filter caching)
- Bonus: `must_not` = NOT condition

Comment: Thanks Val, can you just please also explain to me the difference between filter vs [must/should]

Comment: Also, it's not always the case when I get yes/no answers. I am using `matchQueries as well where scoring matters, In that scenario what do you suggest.

Comment: Can you give an example? scoring really only makes sense when using full-text queries, is that your case? Using a `match` query doesn't mean that scoring is used.

Comment: Just tested your example with my data-set and it gives me wrong results, much larger than it should and the reason I suspect is because you are using `should[ bool[1 and 2], bool [should [1 or 2]]`  which in my case is wrong, what I need is just opposite: `must[ bool[1 *and* 2], bool [should [1 or 2]]`  but trying this gave me 0 results

Comment: Yes, I do have full-text queries.

Comment: So right now my query does this: `(deleted=0 AND isPrivate=true) OR (isPrivate=false OR (createdBy=xyz AND isPrivate=true))`. Can you express how the boolean logic should look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195661/discussion-between-neeraj-jain-and-val).

Comment: according to our chat discussions, I've updated my query